# Repeat Header Row With Each Row In the Table IN SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS and I want it to display like this (header row repeats per data row):

```
Id Name
1  John 
Id Name
2  Jack
```

How can I do that?

I have a row group which creates a new record for every new value of Id, but I can't get the header row to display before each record.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use an actual header row. Add another row to your details group, and set the data in that row to be static text. (Type directly into the cell.)

The entire details group, no matter how many rows, will be repeated for each record in the dataset.

The details group is indicated by the small lines to the left that I circled in the screen shot below.
[image]

Comment: clever and simple solution. never taught of this before.... kudos for simplicity.